# Actionbar menu not showing for android 4.X, but works on 2.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to inflate a new menu in a fragment. This code works for android 2.2 but not for 4.X... I'm using actionbar compat. Logcat outputs the "create menu" log.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
//(...)
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.i("create menu");
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.textarea_actions, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

and the menu XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:dealer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <item android:id="@+id/action_save"
         android:icon="@drawable/action_check"
         dealer:showAsAction="always"
         android:title="Submit"/>
</menu>
```

This code works in android 2.2. Here is a print:

[image]

In android 4.X the button are not shown, however if I select the text for copy/paste, android will replace the action bar by the system actionbar of copy/paste/cut. When I deselect the text the actionbar of my app reappears, but this time with the button...

Here are some prints:

[image]

This is a strange problem, I tried to refresh the action bar, but I was unsuccessful...

Comment: Try to change attr dealer:showAsAction to android:showAsAction

Comment: Didn't work.. With actionbar compat I think is appname:showAsAction

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your 4.x emulator have a physical menu button? This would cause the app to not show the overflow menu.

Comment: I have... I removed the buttons of the emulator and didn't work aswell... When I click on the textarea, the button appears too...

Answer (score 0):

Well I continued developing and the problem seems ok (not solved, but worked around).

This part of the app is based on one activity and I only switch fragments. I just added the menus in the firsts fragments and the menu now appears on this fragment...